# I receive an error that my function expects 2 inputs, but I do put two inputs

Tags: function, netlogo

I define the following function :

```
 to-report J [ num1 num2 ] 
 ifelse (num1 = 3 or num2 = 3)  [report 16]
[ifelse (num1 = 1 and num2 = 1) [report 14]
 [ifelse (num1 = 2 and num2 = 2) [report 2]
   [ ifelse ((num1 = 1 and num2 = 2) or (num1 = 2 and num2 = 1 )) [report 11] 
      [report 0]
    ]
  ]
 ]

end
```

and later I used it in a patch procedure, I define cell type as 0 or 1 as a variable for patches and I update like this

```
 to update

   let c-t cell-type
   let c-t_1 [ cell-type ] of patch-at 1 0
   let energy_neighbors  J[ c-t c-t_1 ]   

end
```

and it tells me, J expects two inputs. Even if in my code I put J [ 1  2 ], it stills tell me that it expects two inputs.

Any ideas if I'm not defining correctly the function? or calling it in correctly? Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets are to blame! Brackets are used for code blocks and lists, but not for parameters when calling procedures. Just remove them:

```
let energy_neighbors J c-t c-t_1
```